# I believe hacker got into network and has service running

Tags: network

I have a modem running on a different subnet than I have my access point running. My modem is connected directly through an ethernet cable to my access point and then I have my Wi-Fi devices connected to that.

192.168.0.1 is my modem 192.168.1.1 is WAP and I believe 192.168.1.254 is the hacker.

I can no longer log onto my modem web interface but no issues with WAP. I did a nmap scan and attached the output.

Can someone please explain what is going on or why I can't access the modem web interface? I think they basically have it blocked sitting behind whatever service they running on tomato.

Also, is there anything I can run or do to find out more? I believe 401 is unauthorized user so they put user name and password on .xxx.xxx.1.254

Summary of Nmap results

```
Discovered open port 111/tcp on 192.168.0.254
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 192.168.0.254
Discovered open port 443/tcp on 192.168.0.1
Discovered open port 5000/tcp on 192.168.0.1
Discovered open port 20005/tcp on 192.168.0.254
Discovered open port 1900/tcp on 192.168.0.1
Completed SYN Stealth Scan against 192.168.0.254 in 11.65s (2 hosts left)
Completed SYN Stealth Scan against 192.168.0.1 in 11.71s (1 host left)
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 02:15, 11.93s elapsed (3000 total ports)
Initiating Service scan at 02:15

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1

Host is up (0.015s latency).
Not shown: 992 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT     STATE  SERVICE      VERSION
22/tcp   closed ssh
23/tcp   closed telnet
139/tcp  closed netbios-ssn
443/tcp  open   https?
445/tcp  closed microsoft-ds
1900/tcp open   http
|_http-title: Site doesn't have a title.
| http-methods: 
|_  Supported Methods: GET POST
5000/tcp open   tcpwrapped
8443/tcp closed https-alt
Aggressive OS guesses

Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.254

Host is up (0.016s latency).

Not shown: 995 closed tcp ports (reset)

PORT      STATE    SERVICE   VERSION
21/tcp    filtered ftp
80/tcp    open     http      lighttpd 1.4.55
| http-methods: 
|_  Supported Methods: GET HEAD POST OPTIONS
| http-auth: 
| HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\x0D
|_  Basic charset=UTF-8 realm=root
|_http-title: 401 Unauthorized
|_http-server-header: lighttpd/1.4.55
111/tcp   open     rpcbind   2 (RPC #100000)
| rpcinfo: 
|   program version    port/proto  service
|   100000  2            111/tcp   rpcbind
|_  100000  2            111/udp   rpcbind
8443/tcp  filtered https-alt
20005/tcp open     btx?
Device type: WAP
Running: Linux 2.6.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6.22
OS details: Tomato 1.28 (Linux 2.6.22)
Uptime guess: 34.730 days (since Mon Feb 27 07:47:32 
202
```

Comment: Nothing you described is evidence of a "hacker".

Comment: *"So I can no longer log onto my modem web interface"* - Reset the modem to the factory settings, configure it to use HTTPS, change password.

Comment: So what's is running on 192.168.254 running tomatoe

Comment: I only have my ap xxx.xxx.1.1 is eth connects to  192.168.0.1 on 192.168.0.26 N nothing is on 254

Comment: Not to mention the day before I noticed logins not from my localnet so obviously someone got in

Comment: I think this requires a second look at the networking setup or the details. You scanned the 192.168.0.0/24 network? Therefore you scanned the *modem* network. There is no **192.168.1.254** in the results, but a **192.168.0.254**. So, that could be the 192.168.0.0 side of the WAP ... As mentioned, there is nothing here that indicates any "hacker". You can't log into the modem interface? Are you connected to the modem network? Did you lose access when you made a networking change?

Comment: most likely the unknown device is your WAP and it's set up wrong.